# Как выбрать только уникальные (неповторяющиеся) строки

Tags: jquery, php

исходные значение:

```
$masConsoles=array('super', '1', '24', 'internet', 'nash', 'tvoi', 'tvoy', 'online', 'Web', 'top', 'magazin', 'sait', 'info', 'ooo', 'euro', 'evro', 'prodazha', 'mega', 'vip', 'gorod', 'bel', 'new');
```

Входящие значение
$masIcxod=array('info', '1', 'euro', 'gorod', 'nash')

Как выбрать уникальные 5 записей из массива  $masConsoles, чтобы не повторялись входящему массиву(masIcxod)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_slice array_unique array_diff

Comment: array_diff он то что надо
спасибо)